# Prove complex Fourier Series in 2D

Tags: complex-analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

Prove the complex form of Fourier Series in 2Dimension from periodic function (period $2\pi$) in $x$ and $y$, defined in region $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R^2}$

$$f(x,y)\sim\sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} \sum_{-\infty}^{\infty} c_{m,n} e^{i(mx+ny)}$$

where,

$$c_{m,n} = \frac{1}{4\pi^2} \int_{\Omega}\int f(x,y)\,\,e^{-i(mx+ny)}dxdy$$

I know solve for case 1D. But, on this case, I`m very confused to organized these terms from expression.

Comment: separating of x and y doesn't help?